# Why names() function does not show up in sys.calls() output stack - R

Tags: r, stack, primitive

I defined the following function in R to test the output of `sys.calls()`, a function that returns the function calling stack:

```
show_syscall_stack = function() {
  print(sys.calls())
  invisible(list(x=2, y=3))
}
```

I observed the following two behaviours:

**1) Calling `names()` on the output of this function does not show `names()` as part of the function calling stack**

Interestingly enough, when I run:

`names(show_syscall_stack())`

I get the following output (where the `names()` function does not appear as part of `sys.calls()`'s returned value):

```
[[1]]
show_syscall_stack()

[1] "x" "y"
```

**2) Calling `ls()` on the output of this function *does* show `ls()` as part of the function calling stack (as expected)**

Instead when I run:

`ls(show_syscall_stack())`

I get the following output (where the `ls()` function *does* appear in the stack returned by `sys.calls()`):

```
[[1]]
ls(show_syscall_stack())

[[2]]
tryCatch(name, error = function(e) e)

[[3]]
tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)

[[4]]
tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])

[[5]]
doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)

[[6]]
show_syscall_stack()

[1] "x" "y"
```

**I would like to understand if:**
a) this behaviour happens because `names()` is a primitive function (see `?names`).
b) primitive functions fall into the concept of "contexts", to which `sys.calls()` does not have access as mentioned in the following paragraph of `?sys.calls` (`Details` section):

> Notice that even though the sys.xxx functions (except sys.status) are interpreted, their contexts are not counted nor are they reported. There is no access to them.

---

My platform:

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Comment: Thanks @joran for pointing to this other question. And yes, I would say mine is a duplicate but  I am afraid I cannot mark it as such, can I?

Nevertheless, I would like to understand the meaning of "context" as mentioned in my question (b) in my post.